# How to give image path for background url

Tags: html, css, image, angular

I am giving background image to hr tag like this.

`<hr style="height:6px;background: url(http://ibrahimjabbari.com/english/images/hr-11.png) repeat-x 0 0;border: 0;margin:0px!important">`

Now i have saved the image locally. How can i set the path of my image in the above url.

My folder structure is

In app folder i have css, images, ts.

Inside ts i have html page and the above code. 
inside images i have "hr-11.png".I specified path like this.

```
background: url('../images/hr-11.png').
```

But its not taking that path and no image is there. How can i correctly give the url path.

Comment: Locate images relative to your HTML file.

Comment: how to locate images relative to html??

Comment: if ur html is inside the **ts** folder, and the image saved inside the the **images** folder, ur code should be working

Comment: @ Abbr But its not working. Am i missing something.?

Comment: can you please specify height and width both

Answer (score 0):

This will help you & inside example.html:

```
<hr style="background:url('../images/hr-11.png') repeat-x top left; border: 0"></hr>
```

also check with: background-image: url('../images/hr-11.png');

```
App
 |-images
 |-css
 |-ts
   |-example.html
```

Comment: Example.html  should be inside another folder named 'ts' in app. Then how the path we have to specify

Comment: If i give any url like http its working. But its not working for local images.

Comment: Whether there will be any change if it is in angular 2

Comment: in angular 2 + if you have image inside folder, **src/assets/images** , then from your component template reference it as **('../assets/images/file.png') 
 give folder path that '../../..' based on your template folder location.** .

Comment: Tried this also. But not getting

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the path. The correct path should be like: `background: url(images/hr-11.png) repeat-x 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

There are rules for url routing:

**./images** will go one level up. which means, if you are in css folder and you have a container folder of content for example, the path will search one level up meaning, content/images.

```
App
 |-content
   |-images
     |-example.png
   |-css
     |-example.css
```

**../images** will go two levels up,  if you are in css folder and you have a container folder of content for example, the path will search two levels up meaning, main_project/images.

```
 App
  |-images
       |-example.png
     |-content
       |-css
         |-example.css
```

**~/images** will search the entire folder for the given file, 
for example from MVC:

```
~/Scripts/angular.js
```

**/ Or non at all** - Will search the current main folder:

```
Html/Index.html

App
 |-Html
     |-Index.Html
```

Comment: app-images-hr.png is  where image is. app-ts-example.html is my html file. from example.html i need to acces  hr.png. i tried ../images/hr.png

Comment: You can name your image what ever you want, I gave you a brief explanation what every style means :) according to my explanation, you can see where your folder stands in the hierarchy and create the relevant path